# nginx SSL_do_handshake() failed

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

it's the first time I configure an SSL certificate on my development machine (I'm no sysadmin - I need SSL to work with facebook). I decided to go with ngingx proxying a ruby sinatra application, nothing fancy.

This is the error I get when Facebook tries to connect to my HTTP server. AFAIK nginx is the culprit here:

```
2015/11/26 15:42:03 [info] 42872#0: *3 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:SSL alert number 48) while SSL handshaking, client: 31.13.113.70, server: 0.0.0.0:4567
```

This is what I did:

1. Downloaded the cert (a .key, a .crt and a .csr) from RapidSSL
2. Downloaded the trusted cert from RapidSSL (https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/library/VERISIGN/ALL_OTHER/RapidSSL%20Intermediate/RapidSSL_CA_bundle.pem) and saved locally under /etc/ssl/cert/
3. Installed locally nginx and configured like this:

   ```
   upstream server {
     server 0.0.0.0:8080;
   }

   server {
     listen 4567  default_server ssl;
     server_name  sandbox.thing.it;
     ssl_certificate  /Users/ngw/thing/server.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /Users/ngw/thing/server.key;
     ssl_stapling on;
     ssl_stapling_verify on;
     ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/cert/RapidSSL_CA_bundle.pem;
     resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
     resolver_timeout 10s;

     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
     ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
     ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://server;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
   }
   ```
4. Restarted both nginx and puma respectively on port 4567 and 8080
5. Went to https://sandbox.thing.it, the app responded as expected, the connection was encrypted and the certificate appears to be the correct one.
6. Went to Facebook and attempted to register a new page subscription (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/v2.2). Had the error reported on the top (SSL_do_handshake() failed) when Facebook attempted to validate my callback url

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why is nginx listening on port 4567? The standard https port is 443.

Comment: It's just that if I change it I need to mess around with some other configurations on the office's router. I don't think that the port is significant honestly...

Comment: How do you know that Facebook is actually reaching your nginx server, then? Maybe it's talking to the office's router.

Comment: I put the callback url myself and I specify the port + I see a new entry with matching timestamp in my error_log.

Comment: You forgot to mention that in your question.

Comment: I have same problem, can't receive webhook from Shopify, though requests from curl come just good.